# Can you tell me which webrtc is wrong using websocket in the Go code?

Tags: javascript, go, websocket, webrtc

I encountered the following error while working on a simple webrtc project. How should I deal with it? I'll refer to the front and back end codes together.

This is error Message:

> Error handling answer: DOMException: Failed to execute
> 'setRemoteDescription' on 'RTCPeerConnection': Failed to set remote
> answer sdp: Called in wrong state: stable

Frontend code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>WebRTC Example</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>WebRTC Example</h1>
<video id="localVideo" autoplay></video>
<video id="remoteVideo" autoplay></video>
<script>
    const ws = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8080/ws');

    const localVideo = document.getElementById('localVideo');
    const remoteVideo = document.getElementById('remoteVideo');

    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true, audio: true })
        .then(stream => {
            localVideo.srcObject = stream;

            const pc = new RTCPeerConnection();

            // Add local stream to RTCPeerConnection object
            stream.getTracks().forEach(track => {
                pc.addTrack(track, stream);
            });

            // Handle ICE candidates sent by the other peer
            ws.addEventListener('message', async (event) => {
                let message = event.data;
                if (typeof message === 'string') {
                    message = JSON.parse(message);
                } else if (message instanceof Blob) {
                    message = await message.text();
                    message = JSON.parse(message);
                }
                if (message.type === 'candidate') {
                    try {
                        await pc.addIceCandidate(message.candidate);
                    } catch (error) {
                        console.error('Error adding ICE candidate:', error);
                    }
                } else if (message.type === 'offer') {
                    try {
                        await pc.setRemoteDescription(new RTCSessionDescription(message));
                        const answer = await pc.createAnswer();
                        await pc.setLocalDescription(answer);
                        ws.send(JSON.stringify({
                            type: 'answer',
                            sdp: pc.localDescription.sdp
                        }));
                    } catch (error) {
                        console.error('Error handling offer:', error);
                    }
                } else if (message.type === 'answer') {
                    try {
                        await pc.setRemoteDescription(new RTCSessionDescription(message));
                    } catch (error) {
                        console.error('Error handling answer:', error);
                    }
                }
            });

            // Send ICE candidates to the other peer
            pc.addEventListener('icecandidate', (event) => {
                if (event.candidate) {
                    ws.send(JSON.stringify({
                        type: 'candidate',
                        candidate: event.candidate,
                    }));
                }
            });

            // Display remote video stream when available
            pc.addEventListener('track', (event) => {
                remoteVideo.srcObject = event.streams[0];
            });

            // Create offer and send it to the other peer
            pc.createOffer()
                .then(offer => {
                    pc.setLocalDescription(offer);
                    ws.send(JSON.stringify({
                        type: 'offer',
                        sdp: pc.localDescription.sdp
                    }));
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    console.error('Error creating offer:', error);
                });
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.error('Error getting user media:', error);
        });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Backend code:

```
package main

import (
    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
    "github.com/gorilla/websocket"
    "log"
    "net/http"
)

func main() {
    r := gin.Default()
    r.LoadHTMLFiles("index.html")

    r.GET("/", func(c *gin.Context) {
        c.HTML(200, "index.html", nil)
    })

    r.GET("/ws", func(c *gin.Context) {
        echo(c.Writer, c.Request)
    })

    r.Run(":8080")
}

var upgrader = websocket.Upgrader{} // use default options

func echo(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    c, err := upgrader.Upgrade(w, r, nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Print("upgrade:", err)
        return
    }
    defer c.Close() 
    for {
        mt, message, err := c.ReadMessage()
        if err != nil {
            log.Println("read:", err)
            break
        }
        log.Printf("recv: %s", message)
        err = c.WriteMessage(mt, message)
        if err != nil {
            log.Println("write:", err)
            break
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to change the order without "await" in JavaScript, but it didn't work out. I changed the backend to Node.js and proceeded it, and it was handed over without any errors, so I think there will be a problem with the backend part, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1):

To me, this indicates that you are trying to set a remote answer on a connection that already has a remote description set. Basically, you are likely getting a collision of offers/answers, where both sides are creating offers and answers.

Basically, you need a way to resolve these conflicts so that when you need to establish a connection between two webrtc peers, you will have one creating an offer and the other one creating an answer. One way of doing it is to let a new peer joining a conference create an offer. Mozilla has a detailed scenario spelled out here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebRTC_API/Perfect_negotiation

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert, but I can try to help you!
This could be a CORS issue, meaning that there is no communication between your front-end and back-end code.
To solve this problem, you can use the package github.com/gin-contrib/cors and add this code:

```
import (
"github.com/gin-contrib/cors"
"github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
)

func main() {
r := gin.Default()
r.Use(cors.Default())
}
```

Use the "go get" command to install it before trying to use your program. As I said, I'm new and don't understand much, but I hope this helps!